# MenuFlyoutItem. Текст в TextBox

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте. Так как на UWP Combobox содержит в себе TextBlock, а не TextBox, то нет возможности редактировать данные. Поэтому пришлось сделать немного иначе. В StackPanel сделать TextBox и Button с FyloutMenu. Проблема в том, что при клике на элемент MenuFlyoutItem нужно сделать команду на вставку текста из этого элемента в TextBox. Я не совсем понимаю как это сделать через Command и CommandParameter. В итоге должно получиться что-то вроде редактируемого Combobox. Или может не стоит изобретать велосипед и найти готовый usercontrol?

```html
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
                                <TextBox x:Name="Genre" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,2" SelectionHighlightColor="Black" BorderBrush="#FF252424" MinHeight="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="260"/>
                                <Button Width="40" Height="36">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Up"/>
                                    <Button.Flyout>
                                        <MenuFlyout>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rock" Command="{Binding ElementName=Genre, Path=Text}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Punk Rock"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Post-Rock / Electronica"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Post-Hardcore / Metalcore"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Indie Rock / Indie Pop"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Indie Rock"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Art-Punk"/>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Alt. Rock, Post-Hardcore"/>
                                        </MenuFlyout>
                                    </Button.Flyout>
                            </Button>
```

Comment: Да блин они так сделали глупо. На обычном wpf комбобокс редактируемый. А тут фигня какая-то. Спасибо. Я попробую. Кстати, может есть какой ресурс или nuget пакет с большой сборкой user control, чтобы не изобретать велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

Команды привязываются к командам во вьюмодели, а вы пытаетесь привязаться к элементу разметки. Если есть вьюмодель, то создавайте там команду и в качестве параметра передавайте нужный текст.

Вам нужен редактируемый TextBox с заготовками? Можно взять `AutoSuggestBox` и привязать к нему в качестве `ItemSource` список заготовок. И сделать так, что при фокусе в текстбокc будет вылезать список подсказок, как в поисковиках.

Comment: О, а это и правда неплохо будет. Спасибо за помощь! Кстати, а можно ли тогда в нём сделать так, что бы при вводе текста не показывались предложения, а только при нажатии button отображался список заготовок?

Comment: И еще: можно ли данные подсказок ввести прямиком в xaml, не используя основной код (Через что-то наподобие <ItemsControl/> для ListView или как в комбобокс задаётся контент через <ComboBoxItem/>). Они всё равно никогда не будут меняться, поэтому пусть бы были по дефолту.

Comment: Первое, думаю, сделать легко. Показывать подсказки только по событию фокуса или тапа, а ввод фильтровать. Например, отмечать событие `TextChanged` обработанным, тогда по идее подсказки не будут отображаться при вводе.
Второе тоже, скорее всего, можно сделать, меняя шаблон в XAML. У `AutoSuggestBox` внутри лежит `ListView`, а значит можно наполнить его элементами в разметке.

Answer (score 0):

Назначаем каждом айтему одинаковый клик.

```html
<Button Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" Height="36">
                                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Download"/>
                                        <Button.Flyout>
                                            <MenuFlyout>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rock" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Punk Rock" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Post-Rock / Electronica" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Post-Hardcore / Metalcore" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Indie Rock" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Indie Rock / Indie Pop" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Art-Punk" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Alt. Rock, Post-Hardcore" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" FontSize="14"/>
                                            </MenuFlyout>
                                        </Button.Flyout>
                                    </Button>
```

И обрабатываем его через:

```html
 private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Genre.Text = (sender as MenuFlyoutItem).Text;
        }
```